# In TV listing content, how would you call the schedule for a channel, and the whole set of channel schedules?

Tags: american-english, nouns, word-difference

I'm looking for the correct nouns to name two different concepts:

- a TV channel schedule, e.g. "This is tomorrow *[word-a]* for Channel 5."
- a table with a set of channels and their respective schedule, e.g. "This is the printed weekly *[word-b]* for cable channels."

Said otherwise, what are the correct nouns to use in this sentence: "I've seen Channel 5 *[word-a]* in next week printed *[word-b]* of cable channels.

Are those concepts already well identified with different nouns in American English? If not what would you suggest?

If that helps: In French those two concepts are not well differentiated, we merely use the same noun "programme" in singular and plural forms, e.g. "J'ai regardé *le programme* d'Arte dans *les programmes* de la semaine prochaine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am judging the question correctly. Word A would be "Schedule" and Word B would be "Guide"

> I saw Channel 5's *schedule* in the printed *guide* of cable channels.